# Interface a function to have an optional argument instead of a required one

Tags: c++, c++03

Suppose I use a function (coming from a third-party API, in another namespace) having arguments filled by the function with some information:

```
double foo::f(double x, double& info);
```

When I call it, I have to create a local variable, even if I don't care about the filled value:

```
const double x = 3.14159;
double info = 0.0;
const double y = foo::f(x, info);
// Nothing to do with info
```

Then, I want to interface this function to have an optional argument instead of a reference. Is there an usual/better/easiest/more-readable way than the following to do that ?

```
double ff(double x, double* info = 0)
{
  double unused_info = 0.0;
  double& info_ = ((bool)info ? *info : unused_info);
  return foo::f(x, info_);
}
```

This works, but it looks a little bit clumsy for the need.

*Note: I don't use C++11 for compatibility reasons. But I'm interested by C++11 solutions even if it doesn't answer the question.*

Answer (score 5):

Rather than change the current implementation you can just add an overloaded function with one argument:

```
double f(double x)
{
    double info;
    return f(x, info);
}
```

Comment: Actually, this function is in another namespace. I think it's a bad practice to overload in another namespace. I edit my question to add this information.

Comment: OK - you could probably just create a convenience header which contains overloads such as the above.

Comment: @Caduchon If you can (are alowed to) change a function, you can also overload it, regardless of what namespace it't in.

Comment: @n.m. you really consider safe to overload my own `lapack::dgesvd` ?

Comment: @Caduchon If it's safe to modify the signature of a function, it's equally safe to overload it. Its namespace doesn't matter.

Comment: @Caduchon - That overload doesn't have to be in the same namespace. Just introduce both with a using declaration (into a scope of your choosing), and let overload resolution pick the correct one based on the number of arguments.

Comment: @StoryTeller Then, sometimes I call `mynamespace::f`or `libnamespace::f` for exactly the same functionality. It's quite confusing if I want to change to have the info for debugging (for example). I clearly prefer to have all the declarations in my own namespace when I decide to interface it.

Comment: @Caduchon - `mynamespace` should be `libnamespace_util`, and a combination of using declarations/directives can allow you any kind of uniform prefix you want. Frankly, it seems to me like you are just being overly pessimistic. But it's your party, as they say. Do whatever works for you.